# How to use versioning for a war application running on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, version-control, versioning, war

How to use versioning for a war application running on Apache Tomcat?

My war suffix contains version of the current war like: myApp-web-2.0.1.war

What I want to achieve is create o folder named dist or else in order to see which versions were deployed before the current one.

I would like to hear your approaches, and best practises. Thanks.

Comment: Your `war` name contains a version?Then the `url pattern` of your web application also has a version.This is weird approach

Comment: @user384706, this is recommended approach in a medium enterprise, Application build (by Developer) and Application deployment (be System Administrator) is usually two different jobs handled by different departments. the app built by developer should have suffix version number and we provide deployment instruction to system administrator, usually via JIRA.

Comment: @yorkw:The version number of an application could be known via an "About" link.You mean you actually use URLs that include a version?So for next version you change the URL?And e.g. bookmarks are lost etc?

Comment: @user384706, we don't include version in URL, in the deployment instruction, we write how to deploy war file to a specific app container/server, simply rename it before deploy, we use maven manage build life cycle, for each time we build app, the final build package e.g core-x.x.x.war will be automatically copied to company's internal maven repository, where we keep a historical release war files. My key point is to isolate build phase from deploy phase. Anyway, off topic, probably not a right place to talk here.

Comment: I agree with you yorkw, thanks for explanation.

Comment: @user384706  I already change its name to {ProjectName}.war What I want to achieve is find the appropriate way to keep the previous versions of war files in one of the tomcat directories or else..

Answer (score 0):

Are you building your WAR file with Ant?  Maven would provide a versioning strategy for you inherently with the  tag in your pom.xml.

Assuming you are using Ant, I would recommend keeping your current deployable named myApp-web.war and then copying that artifact out to an archive directory with a `<major>.<minor>.<increment>` extension to keep unique version history on each subsequent build.  If you keep all your historic artifacts in the deploy directory, Tomcat is going to deploy them all which probably is not your desired behavior.  It sounds like you are just after a version archival.

Comment: I already generate my war with named has version as i mention in my question above.. What I would like to know is the way to keep different war's in which tomcat folder. Thanks.